# Should parboiled rice be washed/rinsed before cooking?

Tags: rice, water

Should parboiled rice be washed or rinsed before cooking? If yes, on average how many times it should be washed. Should it be rinsed in water for more than 10 minutes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Par boiled should not be rinsed, it is ready to be cooked as-is.

It was already rinsed and cleaned and, erm, par boiled.

If unsure, check the instruction on the package.

Comment: The package doesn't mention anything about washing or rinsing.

Answer (score -1):

All rice should be washed and rinsed unless you are using it to make Risotto.

Comment: Opinions, like yours here, vary on this. Rinsing removes some starch, and in some cases the starch is desired to be maintained and maximized. A good answer at SE will have details and sources and enough info that the asker feels confident. THis isn't a chat room conversation, but a place for solid answers others can refer to later.